# How to avoid "System.CalloutException" in test

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I have two triggers: One for any insert/update/delete/undelete on an Account, and one for the same events on a custom object named Program__c. Both of these make a call to another class: `Webhook.callout()`, announcing the change.  The `Webhook.callout` function has `@future(callout=true)`. Both triggers are working exactly as expected.

My tests for the account trigger work great. I implement and enable HTTPCalloutMock, I create an SObject with bogus values, insert/update/delete, and all goes well.

My tests for the Program__c trigger are nearly identical, but because Programs are dependent on Accounts (due to a process builder workflow), I *also* have to mock and insert an Account object before I create my Program mock, and then associate the account with it. Because this step fires off a callout due to the Account trigger before the callout due to the Program trigger, I get this error in my Program insert test:

`System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

How can I test this trigger? Test code is here:

```
@isTest static void testInsertTrigger() {
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ProgramWebhookTriggerTest());

    // Dependencies
    SObject opp = mock('Opportunity');
    insert opp; // No trigger
    SObject acc = mock('Account');
    insert acc; // Fires a trigger

    SObject o = mock('Program__c');
    o.put('Opportunity_Name__c', opp.get('Id'));
    o.put('Account__c', acc.get('Id'));

    Test.startTest();
    insert o; // Fires a trigger
    Test.stopTest(); // Exception fires here

    // Check the URL
    System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
    System.assertEquals('https://trigger.test/forcehub/sf-record-change', request.getEndpoint());

    // Check the request body
    Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(firstRequest.getBody());
    System.assertNotEquals(null, jsonResponse.get('userId'));
    System.assertEquals('create', jsonResponse.get('action'));
}
```

And here's `Webhook.callout`:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void callout(String content) {
    Http h = new Http();
    Hub_Integration__c opts = Hub_Integration__c.getValues('Default');
    String url = opts.Base_URL__c + '/forcehub/sf-record-change';
    String token = opts.Token_Part_1_2__c + '.' + opts.Token_Part_3__c;

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    req.setBody(content);

    h.send(req);
}
```

To reiterate, this same code is 100% working for my Account tests, in which I don't define or insert any dependencies.

Help!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue the other day and a general solution to this is to use the [Separation of Concerns pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns). Fortunately, since I do use this pattern, the solution was straightforward

Elements to the solution:

- A Domain layer that does all the work around an SObject itself; one of the primary functions, but not exclusively, is a trigger handler. This is covered here in this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Domain_Layer). Your trigger is one line.
- A Selector layer that has a separate class (w/ methods) for each queryable Sobject.  Covered in [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Selector_Layer). **All your SOQL goes in here**.
- A mocking framework that allows any method in the selector layer to return mocked results, thus avoiding DML in testmethod setup. Covered in [this blog post](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/22/unit-testing-with-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-1/).

All covered entirely here in [this Dreamforce session](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/7QtP2628KmtXfmiwI-7B1w%20) plus corresponding (terrific) book and in various blog posts under [andyinthecloud](https://andyinthecloud.com/). I've omitted for purposes of this answer the Service and Unit of Work layers but those have tremendous utility too.

Essentially, by making your code more granular with a well-defined separation of concerns, you can mock the results of soql queries without having to insert objects and, in your case, make callouts for the Account.

Moreover, a clever trick, not well known by all, is that Sobjects can be created with valid ID fields without having to do an insert.  For example, see this class [fflib_IDGenerator](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks/blob/master/src/classes/fflib_IDGenerator.cls) in the Enterprise Patterns lib.

Adapting to the SoC Pattern is not trivial and there are unsatisfying-in-the-long-run shortcuts, most of which require the use of interfaces to deliver PROD vs test SObjects up to methods. However, there's a [new Trailhead module on this SoC Pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_soc) worth exploring.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the input! Though I think you might be ascribing more complexity to my code than what's there. This is a trigger that's just a couple lines (only because I need to turn the action -- insert, update, etc -- into a string), calling that Webhook.callout function. There's no SOQL, and there's no business logic beyond "receive trigger" and "call out". And the "call out" portion is what I'm already mocking. I definitely see where you're going with the abstraction pattern, but I don't think I can be more granular than I am right now, or how it would impact this error.

Comment: Also -- I should note that I do need to insert the dependent account, because the error I face if I do _not_ is that the process builder flow breaks down trying to look for a nonexistent relationship. My tests were 100% passing without the Account dependency before that flow was added.

Comment: @TomFrost add a condition to your process builder entry condition Account.is_disabled_for_flow__c = false.  Create this new field on Account. In test class, mock this field in Account to true.

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger on `Program__c` makes the callout, then you need to make sure you set the mock in between `startTest` and `stopTest`. That fits with your comment that the error is thrown on your call to `stopTest`, as that call causes all pending `future` calls to run, hence causing the callout.

```
Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(...);
    insert o;
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: I was so hopeful it would be this simple! Unfortunately, this change had no impact to the final result. Thanks for taking the time to suggest!